# RepositoryRestController links self and entity name same url

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I've been playing with spring and RepositoryRestController(on a CrudRepository class) and I've noticed that in the _links there are 2 links that for me are identical:

```
_links":{  
   "self":{  
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/api/nodes/1"
   },
   "node":{  
      "href":"http://localhost:8080/api/nodes/1"
   }
}
```

Is it possible to disable it as i think it will just increase the size of the response and brings no value.

Thank you,
Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

I have found the ticket where the behaviour is explained:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-732